# VS2013 Tips and Tricks: shortcut key to Open existing file in solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013, google-chrome-devtools

I want to know if Visual Studio 13 has any shortcut key to open solution file similar to chrome.

in chrome if you start developers tools and press ctrl + O, it provide a search box to enter the name of file to open..any such feature is available

Answer (score 0):

Found through other post on net

Ctrl + ,   key does the same as Ctrl + O in chrome developer tools.